# Dynamically formatting a string

Tags: java

Before I wander off and roll my own I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to do the following sort of thing...

Currently I am using MessageFormat to create some strings.  I now have the requirement that some of those strings will have a variable number of arguments.

For example (current code):

```
MessageFormat.format("{0} OR {1}", array[0], array[1]);
```

Now I need something like:

```
// s will have "1 OR 2 OR 3"
String s = format(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

and:

```
// s will have "1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4"
String s = format(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

There are a couple ways I can think of creating the format string, such as having 1 String per number of arguments (there is a finite number of them so this is practical, but seems bad), or build the string dynamically (there are a lot of them so this could be slow).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless, I'm missing something this is plain old `join`. Until Java 7 gets String.join (no joke) there are some implementations around like Apache commons lang [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object[],%20char%29).

```
StringUtils.join(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, "OR");
```

The only problem is that is does not work on primtive int[] arrays directly.

Comment: (+1) but the same lib has `ArrayUtils.toObject(..)` to convert the primitive array to the wrapper ;)

Comment: the array is actually String so no issue at all.  I'll go give it a try and see how it does - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

using [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar) should be simple:

```
String s1 = $(1, 3).join(" OR ");
String s2 = $(1, 4).join(" OR ");
```

where `$(1, n)` is a range object wrapper (there are wrappers for `Collection`s, arrays, `CharSequence`s, etc).

Comment: interesting, don't want to add a new dependency to the project, but I'll take a deeper look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method from Java 8 and onwards, which will allow you to join strings with the given delimiter.

```java
String.join(" OR ", "a", "b", "c")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is writing a quick function that runs through the arguments in a `for` loop, appending `“ OR ” + arg[i]` to a StringBuilder, (with a special case for the first argument), then returning the StringBuilder's `toString()` value.  How's this?

```
String format(String... args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(" OR ");
        }
        sb.append(args[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```